# android ant build fails on ant release command

Tags: android, apache, ant, build

I have linux box. I have project on it. I ran "android update project" it worked fine.

Tried using "ant -v release" it throws me error as follows:-

```
    [javac] /home/sto/umakant/dashboard/data/android_apps/lol/project/src/com/glam/lol/Channels.java:90: error while writing <anonymous com.glam.lol.Channels$1>: could not create parent directories
    [javac]             lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
/home/sto/umakant/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:384: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I don't understand whats the problem with it. Why its not allowing me to build the application? Can some one would help me out.

Comment: looks like a permission problem. Check your write permissions on `/home/sto/umakant/dashboard/data/android_apps/lol/project/`

Comment: I saw in winscp. for project folder its :- rwxr-xr-x and 
for Channels.java its :- rw-r--r--

Comment: You must be sure you can write in your "ant-built" folder and subfolders (I think you have a subfolder in read-only)

Comment: "ant-built" folder? Where can I locate it ?

Comment: Yes it was permission problem

Comment: Glad it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was permission problem. Some folders where not having write permission in project.
Now it works fine when permission is corrected.